# Is it possible to extract the adjusted r-squared and p-value of the f-ratio from fable in R?

Tags: r, tsibble, fable

I have used the fantastic fable package to produce multiple ARIMA models with different combinations of external regressors. Is it possible to extract the r-squared (adjusted for degrees of freedom) and the p-value for the f-ratio in a table format similar to glance() i.e. models in rows and 2 cols for the stats?

Output from `glance()`

[image: Output from glance()]

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: The {fable} package doesn't provide R^2 (or adjusted) for ARIMA models as it is not uniquely defined and is not as useful - https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8750/how-can-i-calculate-the-r-squared-of-a-regression-with-arima-errors-using-r

Comment: Thanks Mitchell - the link was very useful. Appreciate the help.